# Applying dtplyr directly to a data.table instead of a lazy_dt

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table, dtplyr

I want to perform several operations intertwining `dtplyr` and `data.table` code. My question is whether, having loaded `dtplyr`, I can apply `dplyr` verbs to a `data.table` object and get optimized `data.table` code as I would with a `lazy_dt`.

I here provide some examples and ask: would `dtplyr` translate to `data.table` code here? Or is simply `dplyr` working?

```r
# Setup for all chunks:
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)
library(dtplyr)
```

a) `setDT`

```r
dataframe # class data.frame
setDT(dataframe)

dataframe %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  mutate(rows_per_group = n())
```

b) `data.table object`

```r
dt <- as.data.table(dataframe) # or dt <- data.table::fread(filepath)
dt %>%
  group_by(id) %>% 
  mutate(rows_per_group = n())
```

Also, if all of them make `dtplyr` work. What is the most efficient option between a), b) and c) using `lazy_dt(dataframe)`?

Comment: The help of lazy_dt says this: "If you have a data.table, using it with any dplyr generic will automatically convert it to a lazy_dt object"